# How to replace REST URL on FORM Action by using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out how to make RESTful URL via JS.
Here's my form.

```
<form id="searchform" action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="id"/>
    <input type="text" name="yourname"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

And below is JS.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click',function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var forms = $(this).parents('searchform');
    var id = forms.attr('id');
    var yourname = forms.attr('yourname');

    var dataString = forms.serialize()+'/'+id+'/'+yourname;

    forms.submit();

});
</script>
```

I'd like to change original form url like '?id=1&yourname=xxx' into '/1/xxx'.
Please let me know where to modify? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what error you are facing?

Comment: Thanks @TechBreak. Unfortunately, nothing happened. I'll describe it on your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the form action before submit as follows,

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click',function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var forms = $('form#searchform');
    var id = forms.find('#yourid').val();
    var yourname = forms.find('#yourname').val();
    //update your action to your url and submit
    var dataString = $(this).attr('action') + '/' + id + '/' + yourname;
    forms.attr('action', dataString).submit();
});
</script>
```

Give `name` to your form, also give `id` to your input elements and use `val()` to get the values

```
<form id="searchform" action="" method="POST" name="searchForm'>
    <input type="text" name="yourid" id="yourid"/>
    <input type="text" name="yourname" id="yourname" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

EDIT : After OP's new requirement, updating method from GET to POST.

Comment: Appreciated! Though I've tried your answer, it won't work. Nothing happen. And when I attach two valuable (id, yourname) by chrome debugger, nothing is shown. Probably, the two valuable can't obtain form data. How do you feel?

Comment: @NoriakiTakamizawa try updated answer. You need to use .val() and find by id. attr() will give you attribute values and not input values.

Comment: @NoriakiTakamizawa glad to help plz accept and upvote :)

Comment: One more thing. URL seems like working. But query_string is still there. Like http://someurl.com/id/yourname/?id=1&yourname=you. How should I eliminate query string?

Comment: @NoriakiTakamizawa i have updated answer. Change the method from get to post it will solve your problem :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129687/discussion-between-techbreak-and-noriaki-takamizawa).

Comment: @NoriakiTakamizawa pleas accept my answer if it helped :)

Comment: Sorry for late reply. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var id = $("input[name=id]").val(),
    yourname = $("input[name=yourname]").val();

  var dataString = $(this).attr('action') + '/' + id + '/' + yourname;
  console.log(dataString); // Submit your form to dataString
});
```

`dataString` will contain the URL that you are expecting. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks!  But after it applied, debugger said 'undefined' for the valuables. Despite of setting ids, it doesn't work so far.

Comment: You do not need to specify IDs for your inputs for your code to work. Here is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hptwiF5gvK7qqZyZzG09) to help you out. Observe the output in the console. This is exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks! You might be right. After put IDs, it works.

Comment: @NoriakiTakamizawa Perhaps you read it wrong. IDs are NOT required at all for your code to work.

Comment: Sorry for that. I mean another 'id'. I put id in the field like this -> <input type="text" id="id" name="id"/> BTW I have another problem to clear. Unfortunately, there's some query strings after url. http://someurl.com/id/name?id=1&name=aaa I can7t figure out how to delete the query strings.